# How get table with references other table in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i have multiple table that join together and i need one query and get all references too !
 **is that possible in yii2??**
get them in hierarchy array ?? 
How ???

> Is it possible to do not use join???

thanks for your help!!!!

[image: sample db]

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use joins?

Comment: its possilbe without join? lazyloading or something!!

Comment: I think joining is better too. Can you tell us more about how you would want your output?

Comment: i want other table is accessible as i query to one table like lazy loading somehow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the model classes for each table using [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) and selected to create the relations in the generated models, you can do something like the following.

1) In your Countries model just change the method that declares the relationship with Airports like this:

```
public function getAirports() {
    return $this->hasMany(Airports::className(), ['country_id' => 'id'])->with('airlines');
}
```

2) When you do the query for the countries and you need to have the related airports, airlines and flightbooked do it like this:

```
$countries = Countries::find()
    ->where('something = something_else')
    ->with('airports')
    ->with('flightbooked')
    ->all();
```

This way you will get all the related models populated with way less queries to the database than using lazy-loading.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give a small suggestion:

As you are maintaining the relations in the tables and if you have generated your code using Gii, then that will generate the joins for you. You can then access any column of any table easily.

But I think `UNION` may not be an alternative to `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use *union all* for this. with this operator, you can concatenate the result sets from multiple queries together, preserving all of the rows from each. Note that a UNION operator (without the ALL keyword) will eliminate any "duplicate" rows which exist in the resultset. The UNION ALL operator preserves all of the rows from each query (and will likely perform better since it doesn't have the overhead of performing the duplicate check and removal operation).

The number of columns and data type of each column must match in each of the queries. If one of the queries has more columns than the other, we sometimes include dummy expressions in the other query to make the columns and datatypes "match". Often, it's helpful to include an expression (an extra column) in the SELECT list of each query that returns a literal, to reveal which of the queries was the "source" of the row.

```
SELECT 'col1' AS source, col23, col343, col33, d FROM table1 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'col2', t2.fee, table2.fi, table2.fo, 'fum' FROM table2 JOIN table3 ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'col3', '1', '2', buckle, my_shoe FROM table4
```

You can wrap a query like this in a set of parenthesis, and use it as an inline view (or "derived table", in MySQL lingo), so that you can perform aggregate operations on all of the rows. e.g:

```
select one.a
     , SUM(one.b)

  FROM (
         SELECT 'q1' AS source, a, b, c, d FROM t1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'q2', t2.fee, t2.fi, t2.fo, 'fum' FROM t2
       ) one
 GROUP BY one.a
 ORDER BY one.a
```

But i think joining tables more suitable. Hope help you